# Manifest Errors After Update to Android Studio 3.0 (AAPT2)

Tags: android, manifest

After I updated the Android Studio to 3.0 I'm having the following error with some third-party libraries:

> Error:(30) error: unknown element < android.widget.TextClock > found.
>   Error:(140) error: unknown element < com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView > found.

I have tried to check for any new syntax for this implementation and I couldn't find any at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#aapt2

Here's my manifest.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.devtt.ttb.encantt"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="32"
    android:versionName="2.31" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="24" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:testOnly="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


        <activity
            android:name="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.clientSummaryActivity"
            android:label="Resumo do Cliente" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.daySummaryActivity"
            android:label="EncanT.T." >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.editClientActivity"
            android:label="Editar Cliente"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateAlwaysHidden" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.saleSummaryActivity"
            android:label="Detalhe da Venda" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.saleCommentActivity"
            android:label="Detalhe da Venda" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.searchActivity"
            android:label="Buscar Clientes" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.optionsActivity"
            android:label="EncanT.T" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.verifyQrActivity"
            android:label="EncanT.T" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.viewCostumer2Activity"
            android:label="EncanT.T" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.searchCommentActivity"
            android:label="EncanT.T" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.preSearchActivity"
            android:label="EncanT.T" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar" />

        <com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView
            android:id="@+id/qrdecoderview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.DecoderActivity" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.devtt.ttb.encantt.com.android.tools.ir.server.InstantRunContentProvider"
            android:multiprocess="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And app gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.devtt.ttb.encantt"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 32
        versionName '2.31'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    api 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    api 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    api 'com.yalantis:ucrop:2.2.0'
    api 'com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview:qrcodereaderview:2.0.2'
    api 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9.4'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It literally states in the error message that you posted, what the error is.

With name and everything.

```
<com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView
            android:id="@+id/qrdecoderview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

That's a view, for layout XML files. It shouldn't be in the manifest.

Comment: It can be android bug before

Comment: Because in older version, it would just be ignored and removed automatically. Now it enforces the rules. It literally even says that in the link that you posted yourself. "In previous versions of AAPT, elements nested in incorrect nodes in the Android manifest are either ignored or result in a warning." straight from the link.

Comment: cheers :)

Looking at the code those snippets makes no sense hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Pedro, You seem new to android

```
<com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView
            android:id="@+id/qrdecoderview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This code never comes to manifest.

The manifest file provides essential information about your app to the Android system, which the system must have before it can run any of the app's code.

Your error simply saying this, so you can resolve this.

> unknown element < com.dlazaro66.qrcodereaderview.QRCodeReaderView >
>   found.